# How to get pycharm to parse a piece of code correctly

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm generally does a good job of recognizing the language I'm using and doing the correct code highlighting, but lets say I have some javascript code embedded in a string in a python file. How can I get pycharm to parse the javascript text within the string as if it was a javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put cursor on your string literal, Alt+Enter, choose 'Inject Language/Reference' from a popup, then select the desired Javascript version in the languages list
See Help, 'Using Language Injections' section